# Excel: How to extract text strings from a formula?

Tags: excel, function, search, excel-formula, formula

I want to split text strings from the below formula in a cell that generates a numeric value.

=RTD($A$1;;"aaa@bbb//ccc////ddd")

Using the mid & search funktion to split certain parts such as =MID(A23; SEARCH("////";A23)+4; 3) only works if text is stored in cells, but not on a formula in the cell.

How to extract strings from a formula?

Comment: Use the `FORMULATEXT` function.

Comment: =MID(FORMULATEXT(A23); SEARCH("////";FORMULATEXT(A23))+4; 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the formulatext function, you can use the find and replace. Replace for exampel the "=" with "@="
Then you can extract what ever you want with the mid function.
When you are done replace "@=" with "="

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment section you can use `FORMULATEXT()`. If you have `TEXTAFTER()` available, try:

```
=LEFT(TEXTAFTER(FORMULATEXT(A1),"////"),3)
```